# Getting Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/NoteTaking/IMG_20170226_231007.jpg while trying to take a photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to make an app that takes a photo and displays it using emulator instead of a device. I followed the steps from this [android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

Part 1) Here is my code where it gets stucks : `file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "edu.android.notetakingapplication.provider", createFileDir());`

This part is in the Mainxml

```
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("NoteTaking", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}
```

Here is my app manifest file's provider section

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="edu.android.notetakingapplication.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="Android/data/edu.android.notetakingapplication/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Part 2) If i keep provider_paths as this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I am able to open camera app, take photo and view it on the same page, but, here is the catch, I am storing the path into database and trying to retrieve all the images on a page. Here is when it gives an error:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/IMG_20170226_230608.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Have you added permissions in Manifest file: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Yes, I have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.

Comment: Can you add this as well READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Sure. But does that come together with WRITE.

    The write permission implicitly allows reading, so if you need to write to the external storage then you need to request only one permission

Comment: No luck. Still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this surely it will work:

```
Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private void operCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && mImageCaptureUri != null && resultCode != 0) {
        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
            String path1 = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            if (path1 != null) {
                File file1 = new File(path1);
                Uri capturedUri = Uri.fromFile(file1);//here you get the URI
                //you can easily get the path from URI if you need
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I actually can get a path, but got this error. 
`Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/tmp_avatar_1488215372729.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`

Comment: Got it... I had to reduce the target api and bam. Was able to click,store and view the photos..

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/IMG_20170226_230608.jpg (No such file or directory)`. Of course you get that error as it is a non valid path for  File object or a file stream. You are saving the uri in a wrong way to the database. You better save File:getAbsoluthePath() instead of Uri:getPath().

Comment: `return new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");`   I changed it in createFileDir(). But still i am getting the same error. I deleted the old database and added new paths to new database.

Comment: Well you are not showing your code that produces the error.. So how could we help? And if your path still starts with "/external_files/P...." then you know you do something wrong.

Comment: ` I am storing the path into database`. Show the code that does this. And tell exactly what is stored. I think the 'path' you put in is already wrong.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have added more parts. Please let me know if you dont understand any part. I did a Log.v to file.getAbsolutePath() before adding the values to database. Its giving me this path.  `/external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/****`

Comment: I added the part where i retrieve the values from database and try to set the image view with the path. Its in Part 2

Comment: I feel its the provider path's file which is creating this.

Comment: `file.getAbsolutePath()` can never give `/external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/****`. As it is a non existing path. I said that before . So you set up `file` wrong already.